# Blank area shows on top and bottom of the image in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem that when i add ImageView in ScrollView it shows empty space on top and bottom both side i want to show image on activity on full screen with width of fill screen and if image is long enough then screen then image will be scrollable. this code some how solve the issue but also showing empty area on top and bottom of the image.

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.alicon.digi.book.ScreenSlideActivity" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bookImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/page_of_book"
        android:src="@drawable/book_title" />

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this and pay attention to **fillViewport** property of ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    **android:fillViewport="true"** //this is imp, see the link for a very good explanation
    tools:context="com.alicon.digi.book.ScreenSlideActivity" >

    <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/bookImage"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:scaleType="fitXY"
           android:contentDescription="@string/page_of_book"
           android:src="@drawable/book_title" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[fillViewPort](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

Comment: Thanks bro i have approved your answer but can't upvote you, because i have not enough reputation

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help. Let know if you need any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` attribute to the `ImageView` XML and change `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` attributes' value from `wrap_content` to `fill_parent`. Use `LinearLAyout` instead of `ScrollView` as follows...

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.alicon.digi.book.ScreenSlideActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bookImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/page_of_book"
        android:src="@drawable/book_title" />

</LinearLayout>
```